# What does 'Vision upon Vision' mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What does the English phrase 'Vision Upon Vision' mean?
I don't remember where I heard it, must have been an online video, but I wrote it down to look it up later. Then I forgot about the phrase for a week or so, but just now I saw it written and I'm asking you.

Comment: Context is needed, but normally it would be interpreted as "one vision after another".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More context is required to understand the full situation at hand, but I'd say with high probability that it means, "one vision after another", or "multiple visions in succession".

Since you're talking about a "vision" (which isn't something physically tangible), it wouldn't make sense to interpret the phrase as "a vision *on top of* another vision", although, that interpretation could still be correct if – say – your event is taking place in a dream (where anything could happen).